# Highlight keyword only on specific lines

Tags: vim, highlight

Sometimes I just want to highlight the keyword on specific lines. Since the keyword is really common, it can appear everywhere in the file.

For instance, I'm searching for `1`s on lines starting with `check` in the following file:

```
...
[block-1]
test 31 for instruction block1_test
stim 011000011100101
check xxxxx1xxxx1xxxx
...
```

Using `/1` will highlight every `1`, and makes it a bit annoying to find the one I want.

Though using `/^check\>.*1` narrowers the search result, it matchs from the very beginning to the last `1` on that line.

I'd like to make all the `1`s on `check` lines clearer to see, to find. Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a look-behind operator [`\@<=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D) in your pattern to match `1` but only in lines that start with `check`.

This search pattern does what you requested:

```
/\(^check\>.*\)\@<=1
```

Using "very magic" option `:h magic`:

```
/\v(^check .*)@<=1
```

Comment: Amazing! I've tried, and that's exactly what I'm looking for. I don't even know this operator. Thank you.